# Angular Testing - How to check if error icon is absent is valid data is passed?

Tags: html, angular, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, tooltip

I am using Selenium webdriver for Angular Automated testing. I display toolip icon with error message if data is invalid.

If data is valid the icon does not appear. I am able to test when icon is present, here is the code. How to test when data is valid and icon is absent?

`Below red icon disappear if correct data is passed. How can I test that?`

[image]

```
function invalidData() {
    it('should display a tooltip when the mouse is hovering the icon', () => {
        const messageIcon = $('#amazonData');
        browser.actions().mouseMove(messageIcon).perform().then(() => {
            const tooltip = $('#invalidData');
            browser
                .wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(tooltip), 2000, 'Expected tooltip to     appear')
                .then(() => {
                    expect(tooltip.getText()).toBe('Data123 does not match Enzyme Commission Number');
                });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `messageIcon` is the icon element? If so, something like the below should work

```
const messageIcon = $('#amazonData');
expect(browser.isElementPresent(messageIcon)).toBe(false);
```